# How to observe LiveData<WorkInfo> of all stages in Chained work with androidx.work.WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am investigating `androidx.work.WorkManager` in my current Android application.

I am using

```
implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc01'
```

I am attempting to schedule chained work and observe the `LiveData<WorkInfo>` for each of the live stages.

I cannot see how to achieve this.

My current code resembles this:-

```
public LiveData<WorkInfo> syncAll() {
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageOne = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0001.class).addTag(STAGE_1_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageTwo = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0002.class).addTag(STAGE_2_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageThree = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0003.class).addTag(STAGE_3_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageFour = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0004.class).addTag(STAGE_4_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork(CHAINED_UNIQUE_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, stageOne).then(stageTwo).then(stageThree).then(stageFour).enqueue();
    return mWorkManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(stageOne.getId());
}
```

My observer only receives stageOne updates.

If I change to

```
public LiveData<List<WorkInfo>>  syncAll() {
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageOne = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0001.class).addTag(STAGE_1_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageTwo = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0002.class).addTag(STAGE_2_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageThree = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0003.class).addTag(STAGE_3_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    final OneTimeWorkRequest stageFour = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0004.class).addTag(STAGE_4_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
    mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork(CHAINED_UNIQUE_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, stageOne).then(stageTwo).then(stageThree).then(stageFour).enqueue();
    return mWorkManager.getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(CHAINED_UNIQUE_NAME);
}
```

My observer receives one update of an empty list of `WorkInfo`s.

How do I observe each stage of a chained sequence of workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getWorkInfosByTagLiveData` isn't the right method.  You are enqueuing a unique work, meaning you need to call `getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData`.  The other method you are calling will also work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution as follows:-

```
        public LiveData<List<WorkInfo>>  syncAll() {
            final OneTimeWorkRequest stageOne = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0001.class).addTag(STAGE_1_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
            final OneTimeWorkRequest stageTwo = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0002.class).addTag(STAGE_2_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
            final OneTimeWorkRequest stageThree = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0003.class).addTag(STAGE_3_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
            final OneTimeWorkRequest stageFour = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Stage_0004.class).addTag(STAGE_4_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();
            final WorkContinuation workContinuation = mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork(CHAINED_UNIQUE_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, stageOne).then(stageTwo).then(stageThree).then(stageFour);
            final LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> workInfos = workContinuation.getWorkInfosLiveData();
            workContinuation.enqueue();

            return workInfos;
        }
```

I feel sure there must be a more elegant method to achieve my desired result though.